# Warnings while loading integer data into table

Tags: mysql, sql, warnings

For some reason, after loading a large amount of data into the following table (from a single file), all of the values register as 0.

```
CREATE TABLE secondTable
(
freq int NULL,
w1 int NULL,
w2 int NULL,
w3 int NULL
)
```

Then loading the data:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE secondTable
```

For some reason, all of the data comes up as 0. The data file is 1.0GB (hardly unprecedented). The datafile also has appropriately formatted headers in the same style as other data files that have successfully been loaded into other tables.

The problem is clearly tied to some sort of warnings during loading:

```
Query OK, 18976277 rows affected, 65535 warnings (5 min 49.74 sec)
Records: 18976277  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 75905108
```

Here are the type of warnings I'm getting:

> ************* 1. row ************* Level: Warning Code: 1265 Message: Data truncated for column 'freq' at row 1
>   ************* 2. row ************* Level: Warning Code: 1366 Message: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'w1' at row 1
>   ************* 3. row ************* Level: Warning Code: 1366 Message: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'w2' at row 1
>   ************* 4. row ************* Level: Warning Code: 1261 Message: Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
>   ************* 5. row ************* Level: Warning Code: 1366 Message: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'freq' at row 2
>   ************* 6. row ************* Level: Warning Code: 1366 Message: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'w1' at row 2
>   ************* 7. row ************* Level: Warning Code: 1366 Message: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'w2' at row 2
>   ************* 8. row ************* Level: Warning Code: 1366 Message: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'w3' at row 2
>   ************* 9. row *************

And here's a look at the first few lines of the file -- it's tab delimited, with each entry on its own line. It *should* work, but isn't!

```
5     298     292    
1     26361     1626     245    
1     167229     9927     19240
```

In Python, the lines look like this (ASCII?):

> \x001\x00\t\x006\x00\t\x002\x008\x001\x005\x001\x00\t\x002\x007\x004\x003\x002\x‌​004\x00\r\x00\n

UPDATE: I solved the problem by using 
    file = codecs.open('data.txt','r','utf16')
in Python, then writing to a new file to open in MySQL. Apparently, it was formatted in Little Endian UTF-16.

Comment: How was data.txt generated, it does not sound like it is properly formatted as it is truncating the very first column of data

Comment: @Anigel It was downloaded from a .zip file and unzipped into Linux (Ubuntu). Perhaps the integers are really formatted as strings?

Comment: It looks like you have spaces between the values instead of tabs and a blank line between each row, that could just be the way SO has formatted your data, but if your data file is properly formatted then these errors go away

Comment: @Anigel I realize that you are correct. Thanks! But that's simply how SO has formatted the data. I'm not sure what the actual formatting problem is, with respect to the actual data file.

Comment: You may have some spaces in the file or may have incorrect line endings. either way, there is no way I can say what is up with the formatting as I can only see how it has been presented here on SO, and as soon as I take the 10 lines of data you gave, replace spaces for tabs, get rid of blank lines and make sure the line endings are just /r it works fine.

Comment: @Anigel I found that the lines look like this (using Python):  \x001\x00\t\x006\x00\t\x002\x008\x001\x005\x001\x00\t\x002\x007\x004\x003\x002\x‌​004\x00\r\x00\n For some reason the text editor shows it as it should look (four integers, tab delimited).

Comment: @Anigel Thanks -- it was your comments that cracked it (see update to question). If you post an answer, I will accept it!